# Error H13 on Heroku when uploading images to Django admin with Gunicorn

Tags: django, heroku

I'm using the Django admin interface to upload images. It had previously worked decently but now gives me Application Errors (H13) when uploading images of only around 1 MB.

Heroku Logs:

```
2012-10-25T04:00:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-10-25 04:00:06 [2] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:13)
2012-10-25T04:00:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-10-25 04:00:06 [2] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:13)
2012-10-25T04:00:06+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H13 (Connection closed without response) -> POST www.website.com/admin/whatever/ dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-10-25T04:00:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-10-25 04:00:06 [68] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapplication.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 10
```

Settings:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku web workers time out after 30 seconds if the request cannot be completed by then. You might be getting this error if your upload speeds are really slow right now and it can't complete the response in 30 seconds. If it's not your upload speeds, it might be the upload speed between Heroku and S3 since it seems like your uploads are directed there.

Comment: Turns out the internet was just awful that night. I already knew about the 30 second rule but seems like S3 was just crawling too. Didn't help that all the thumbnail processing was bouncing back and forth between S3 and Heroku. Icky.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!